# SwiftUI: .onOpenURL action closure is not updating @State property which is of type URL

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, deep-linking

I am implementing my first iOS Application with SwiftUI, in which I want users to be able of clicking on an invitation link for joining a topic group (DeepLinking).
Like joining a WhatsApp-Group with a link.

Therefore I associated my Domain (lets say: https://invite.example.com/) with my Swift-Project.
Whenever I click/open a URL (e.g. https://invite.example.com/313bceff-58e7-40ae-a1bd-b67be466ef72) my app opens and if the user is logged in an the `.onOpenURL` action method is triggered as expected.
However, if I try to save the url in a `@State` URL property in the called closure, it gets not stored.
The `@State` boolean property for showing the sheet is set to `true` though.

That is my code in the @main struct.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var appRouter: AppRouter = AppRouter()
    
    @State private var openAcceptInvitationSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var invitationURL: URL? = nil
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch appRouter.currentScreen {
            case .launch:
                EmptyView()
            case .login:
                LoginSignupNavigationView()
            case let .home(authenticatedUser):
                HomeTabView()
                    .environmentObject(authenticatedUser)
                    .onOpenURL { url in
                        invitationURL = url //Gets not set -> url is not nil here!
                        openAcceptInvitationSheet = true //Is working and sheet will be presented
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $openAcceptInvitationSheet) {
                        //invitationURL is nil -> Why?
                        AcceptInvitationNavigationView(invitationURL: invitationURL!)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Everything else is working here as expected. I guess I have a misconception of how the `@State` properties work. However in all my other views I managed assigning values to `@State` properties in closures which later can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using two variables for your sheet, use one – the optional URL.

```swift
.sheet(item: $invitationURL) { url in
  AcceptInvitationNavigationView(invitationURL: url)
}
```

The optionality of your `URL?` state variable takes the place of the boolean value in determining whether the sheet should display, and the sheet receives the unwrapped `URL` value.

I don't think that your URL is not being set – it's more a question of it's not set at the time the original sheet's closure is evaluated, which is a subtly different SwiftUI object life cycle thing! Sticking to a single object massively simplifies everything. You'll also be able to change your code in `AcceptInvitationNavigationView` to expect a `URL` rather than having to deal with being passed an optional URL.

As noted in comments, this only works if `URL` conforms to `Identifiable`, which it doesn't by default. But you can use a URL's `hashValue` to synthesize a unique identifier:

```swift
extension URL: Identifiable {
  var id: Int { hashValue }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottM. However, the 'URL' must conform to 'Identifiable' to use this approach.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true – although you could add a protocol extension on `URL` and declare `var id: Int { hashValue }` and that'd be good enough for this purpose. Updated the answer.